# Centre of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-groups

How to prove that center of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is scalar matrices?

Again what can you say about the center of set of all upper triangular matrices and center of set of all diagonal matrices.

Comment: Hint: What is the alternative way of defining a centre, other than it being the group of elements which commute with every other element of G?

Comment: sorry I don't know the other definition of centre.

Comment: Yeah, me neither...?

Comment: This is (roughly) the way we defined the centre of a group: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28group_theory%29#Conjugation

Comment: Do note that $ACA^{-1}=C$ if and only if $AC=CA$. The latter is easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a one in the $ij$ position and zeros elsewhere. Note that $I+E_{ij}$ is invertible, and anything which commutes with it commutes with $E_{ij}$. Now compare the entries of $AE_{ij}$ with those of $E_{ij}A$.

For the upper triangular matrices, restrict yourself to $i\le j$.

I'll assume the question on diagonal matrices is a joke.

Comment: In case I am wrong about that last bit, write out the product of two diagonal matrices, and you'll soon get the joke too.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Did you read the second sentence of my answer?

Comment: Now I did, Harald. Good. +1